# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: local part cannot be "null" when creating a QName

Tags: java, soap, xml-parsing

I'm trying to add following xml to my soap body after converting it to document

```
<ns2:OSSRequest xmlns:ns2="http://www.someurl">
<requestBody>
    <property>
        <address>
            <addressId>someValue</addressId>
            <municipality>someValue</municipality>
            <postalCode>someValue</postalCode>
            <province>someValue</province>
            <streetNumber>someValue</streetNumber>
        </address>
    </property>
    <requestedProducts>
        <products>someValue</products>
        <products>someValue</products>
    </requestedProducts>
</requestBody>
<requestHeader/>
```

but I'm getting error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: local part cannot be "null" when creating a QName
```

here is the code I'm using for converting xml to soap body

```
MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage message = factory.createMessage();
SOAPHeader header_soap = message.getSOAPHeader();
SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();
Document document = convertStringToDocument(xml);
body.addDocument(document); // getting error on this line
```

following is the code which is converting xml to document

```
private Document convertStringToDocument(String xmlStr) {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    try {
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlStr)));
        return doc;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Is my xml invalid ? Or I'm missing any configs while adding it to document ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post, looks like you need to add an element to your header specifying the QName and localPart.

[SOAP call fails when deployed on websphere but works fine on tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60399029/soap-call-fails-when-deployed-on-websphere-but-works-fine-on-tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

After whole hours in searching, I just wanted to share the Answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312514/local-part-cannot-be-null-when-creating-a-qname/74626244#74626244) helped me with a Talend code migration - involving SOAP messages - from java8 to java11.

```
// Used libraries
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

...

// This is the node I want to replace: "<DataArea><Contact/></DataArea>"
// <SOAP-ENV:Body> > SOAP Action (e.g. <ns:GetContact>) > <GetContactRequest> > <DataArea>
SOAPBody soapBodyRequest = objSOAPMessage.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getBody();
Node nodeDataArea = soapBodyRequest.getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getFirstChild(); 

// Build a valid Node object starting from a string e.g. "<Contact> etc etc nested-etc </Contact>"
DocumentBuilderFactory objDocumentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

// As per java11, this is essential. It forces the Factory to consider the ':' as a namespace separator rather than part of a tag.
objDocumentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); 

// Create the node to replace "<DataArea><Contact/></DataArea>" with "<DataArea><Contact>content and nested tags</Contact></DataArea>"
Node nodeParsedFromString = objDocumentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(strDataArea.getBytes())).getDocumentElement();
        
// Import the newly parsed Node object in the request envelop being built and replace the existing node.
nodeDataArea.replaceChild(
        /*newChild*/nodeDataArea.getOwnerDocument().importNode(nodeParsedFromString, true), 
        /*oldChild*/nodeDataArea.getFirstChild()
);
```

This throws the **Local part cannot be "null" when creating a QName** exception if you don't put the `.setNamespaceAware(true)` instruction